# Why should I use Microsoft recommended names for Azure private DNS Zones

Tags: azure, azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

MS recommends to use very specific names for Azure Private DNS Zones dependent on the platform service it is actually used for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns

I actually would rather use a unique DNS Namespace like *...azure

My question: Are there any good reasons to use the DNS ZoneNames suggested by MS? They do not look like internal DNS Zones at all and have different DNS Namespaces for different services. For me that's rather confusing...
Are there even any functional constrains not using MS suggested naming conventions?

For our Azure Private DNS Zonenames I'd like to use a naming scheme like: *...azure rather than MS suggested names here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns

Comment: The document specifically says _"Private endpoint private DNS zone configurations will only automatically generate if you use the recommended naming scheme in the following table."_ - so if you don't follow their naming convention then you won't get automatic records management working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> I agree by @Dai, as per [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#azure-services-dns-zone-configuration) Private endpoint private DNS zone configurations will only automatically generate if you use the recommended naming scheme.

[image]

While using your own custom domain name is not functionally restricted, Microsoft suggests specified naming patterns for Azure Private DNS zones. and note that using a unique DNS namespace like *...azure may cause confusion and make it difficult to manage your DNS zones in the future.

> It is recommended to use Microsoft's suggested naming conventions to reduce the potential confusion and misconfiguration.

Additionally, once you have created the DNS zone, you can link it to your virtual network and configure DNS records for your resources. You can also enable auto registration on a virtual network link, which will automatically register the DNS records for the virtual machines in that virtual network in the private zone.

[image]

***Reference***:

[Azure Private Endpoint DNS configuration | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns)